# Loop a array of string to a text box and post from a submit form with the changes angular 7

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms, angular7

Hi am sure this is asked before but am not able to find an answer here. 
i have an array of string which is loop and rendered as text box inside a form while submitting the form all the value with new changed value should submit to onSubmit()

```
 <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="caption" [(ngModel)]="blockdummyJson.Properties.Caption" #Caption="ngModel"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && Caption.invalid }" required />
  <div *ngIf="f.submitted && Caption.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="Caption.errors.required">radio button caption is required</div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="addOption" (click)="addOptionToRadioOption()" />

  <div *ngFor="let option of blockdummyJson.Properties.Options; let i = index">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="blockdummyJson.Properties.Options[i]" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

in side component

```
radioOption:any=[];
  data: any;
  blockdummyJson: any;
  blockName: string = 'OptionBuildingBlock';
  activityInfo: any;

  constructor(private messageservice: MessageService,
    private httpservice: ConfigService,
    private communicationservice: CommunicationService, ) { 

    var self = this;
    this.activityInfo = this.data;

    this.httpservice.getConfig(ConfigValue.apiURI + 'BuildingBlocks/' + this.blockName).subscribe(
      data => {
        self.blockdummyJson = data;
      },
      err => { },
      () => console.log('getting BuildingBlocks config completed')
    )

  }
    addOptionToRadioOption()
      {
        this.blockdummyJson.Properties.Options.push("sample Value");
      }

      onSubmit() {
        debugger;
      }
```

the data coming from server Options include array

```
Options=['test','test1',test2'];
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't you getting error like: *If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form...*??

Comment: no am not getting any error but always in on submit collection of "sample Value"

Comment: So you mean you are getting some error while you call `addOptionToRadioOption()`? If yes, what is that?

Comment: try adding name attribute taht should be unique to each input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already having two way data-binding, on every user input it will get updated to the DOM. Instead of depending ngForm, you are use modelObj.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  blockdummyJson = {
    Properties: {
      Options :['test','test1','test2'],
      Caption: ''
    }
  };

  addOptionToRadioOption()
      {
        this.blockdummyJson.Properties.Options.push(this.blockdummyJson.Properties.Caption);
      }

  onSubmit(formObj){
    console.log(this.blockdummyJson);
  }
```

**Template:**

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.valid && onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="caption" [(ngModel)]="blockdummyJson.Properties.Caption" #Caption="ngModel"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && Caption.invalid }" required />
  <div *ngIf="f.submitted && Caption.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="Caption.errors.required">radio button caption is required</div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="addOption" (click)="addOptionToRadioOption()" />

  <div *ngFor="let option of blockdummyJson.Properties.Options; let i = index">
    <input type="text" name="options-{{i}}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="blockdummyJson.Properties.Options[i]" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

**StackBlitz:**  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsxwuy

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. the issue was with the name duplication. but i have noted one more behavior which very unusual even in you POC. after adding a new text box every time i type a letter the focus going out from the text box why this happening.

Comment: Because the focus is moving to add button. thats the reason. You can programmatically set focus.

Comment: Updated stackblitz code. please refer it. upvote so helpful to others.

Comment: still am not seeing it working in your stackbliz. can you please confirm it